# Element twitches in Chrome - CSS width transition

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition

My element twitches when I use width transition in Chrome. How can I fix this?

```
.search-group input {
   width: 85px;
   -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
   transition: all ease-in-out .15s;
}
.search-group input:focus {
   width: 150px;
   outline: none;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7uWL/)

[VIDEO](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=4jop3s%3E&s=8#.U5HosfmwI3g)(sorry for quality)

Comment: What browser do you use? In firefox it looks fine.

Comment: @HristoValkanov, chrome 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: @totoro2, hm, strange...

Comment: @totoro2, http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=4jop3s%3E&s=8#.U5HosfmwI3g - look on the right part(sorry for quality).

Comment: I had that kind of problem before but with opacity transition. I think I managed to fix it by including `-moz-`, `-ms`, and `-o-` which made no sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think i fixed it. I added:

```
.window_label{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7uWL/1/)

At least on my machine it fixes the twitching for Chrome. I found out that it was a official bug, as stated [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/), [here](http://yuji.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/css3-animation-twitch-bug-on-opacity-fade/) and many other places on the Internet.

As stated in the comments, this bug affects elements with altered opacity.

EDIT: Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7uWL/2/). I think I fixed it. I'm leaving the above resolution because it can serve someone. Anyway the problem was with

> display:table

It was bugged and when the extra '}' appeared, it nullified the '.search-group' field css.

I moved the display option form there to '.header-search' and here is the end result:

```
.header-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 10px;
    display: table;
}
.search-group {
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: table-row;
    float: right;
}
```

for me it solves the problem. Try it and tell me if it fixes it for you too.

Comment: But on my live project I can't understand which elements should have this CSS property.

Comment: in the case you provided it was the square in the end, the one that says 'Result'. If this doesn't help, consider the following: The bug happens on elements with altered opacity. You should target them first.

Comment: Look, you Jsfiddle has two } - .window_label{ -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} }. If i remove one the problem returns. Strange.

Comment: Unfortunately, I should unaccept your answer because it doesn't work. Example in CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pByCv

Comment: Thank you. I just removed `display:table`. And everything is ok.